# hive: union_map 'invalid function'

Tags: hadoop, hive

I try to use union_map to aggregate combine maps during rows aggregation and I get: `Invalid function 'UNION_MAP'`. i found the function here: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hive/builtins/UDAFUnionMap.html

do i miss some jars? union_map is supposed to be a standard function, right? at least according

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find a reference about such a thing? And what makes you think it could be "standard" although it is *not mentioned anywhere in the Hive documentation*, cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: Hive 0.10 was followed by 0.11 - 0.12 - 0.13 - 0.14  - 1.0  - 1.1 - 1.2 - 2.0 and some things clearly fell off the train. See for instance how [HIVE-1545] is "unsolved" and has been inactive for the last 30 months... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1545

Comment: Maybe the feature was rebuilt into another UDAF with another name. Look into the docs for *current* version of Hive. Or search GitHub, maybe there's a custom patch somewhere (Brickhouse?)